# How practical is it to roll your own authentication and authorization?

Tags: authentication, authorization

I am looking to secure APIs, and I am wondering how practical it is to roll your own authentication and authorization service?

Are there any good examples of this or are following the OAuth specifications the best I can hope for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did not receive an answer for this question, however I have come to the realization that it's not recommended to re-create your own authentication and authorization system due to many edge cases involved with the OAuth spec.

However, I did stumble upon many open source identity solutions which you can configure and deploy:

1. https://github.com/ory
2. https://github.com/dexidp/dex
3. https://github.com/authelia/authelia
4. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak
5. https://www.gluu.org/
6. https://github.com/accounts-js/accounts

(plus many other alternates in the source link)

source: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25212694